# when accessing Json file in jar (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, resources, executable-jar

I need to access some data that it stored in a Json file that is in Resources file. The code compiles in eclipse but when I try to Export and run as JAR file I get this exception:

[image]

The location of the Json file is:

[image: Resource folder]

I tried to use:

> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
> .getResourceAsStream("AutomationJson.json");

or

> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
> .getResourceAsStream("/AutomationJson.json");

```
    Main(){

       InputStream jsonFileStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AutomationJson.json");
       String jsonString = readFromJARFile();
       jsonData();

    }


    private void jsonData() {

       JsonNode node = null;
       try {
           node = JsonHelper.parse(jsonString);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       secondUserName = node.get("secondUserName").asText();
       password = node.get("password").asText();
    }

    public String readFromJARFile() throws IOException {
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(jsonFileStream);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
       }
       br.close();
       isr.close();
       return sb.toString();
    }
```

The Json helper class:

```
public class JsonHelper {

private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = getDefaultMapper();

static ObjectMapper getDefaultMapper() {
    
    ObjectMapper defaultMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    defaultMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return defaultMapper;
    
}

public static JsonNode parse(String src) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
    return objectMapper.readTree(src);
    
}
```

}

Comment: In what line in your code does the exception happen? This should be listed somewhere in the exception's callstack. And if you replace `getRessourceAsStream()` by `getRessource()` and then print the return value, does the printed path match the actual path of the file?

Comment: The line that the exception is called is
 `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(jsonFileStream);` at the function `readFromJARFile`
When I print `getRessource()` I get the URL `file:/D:/Project_File/Project_name/target/classes/AutomationJson.json`
The JSON file exists in this file and at `D:\Project_File/Project_name\src\main\resources/AutomationJson.json`
@MDK

Comment: Can you update the question with code that would compile? Currently `jsonFileStream` is not even passed to  `readFromJARFile()` method.